# determine a in matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Determine the value of a if the system 
$$\begin{align}
x_1 + 4x_2 − 3x_3 + 2x_4 &= 0\\
2x_1 + 7x_2 − 4x_3 + 4x_4 &= 0\\
−x_1 + ax_2 + 5x_3 − 2x_4 &= 0\\
3x_1 + 10x_2 − 5x_3 + (a² + 4a + 1)x_4 &= 0
\end{align}$$
has more then 1 solution

I thought that perhaps I have to work with the Jordan reduction or Gausselimination, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Do you mean $(a^2+4a+1)$ by `(a2 + 4a + 1)`? This is typeset as `$(a^2+4a+1)$`.

Comment: Yes. Sorry; indeed 3x+10x2-5x3+(a²+4a+1)x4=0

Answer (score 1):

We know that a homogeneous linear system has more than one solution if and only if the [rank of the matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29) of the system is less than the number of unknowns. See [Rank-nullity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem).

One of the possibilities how to find rank is to use row operations. You could start like this:
$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 4 & -3 & 2 \\
 2 & 7 & -4 & 4 \\
-1 & a &  5 & -2 \\
 3 &10 & -5 & a^2+4a+1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 4 & -3 & 2 \\
 0 &-1 &  2 & 0 \\
 0 &a+4&  2 & 0 \\
 3 &10 & -5 & a^2+4a+1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 4 & -3 & 2 \\
 0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 &a+4&  2 & 0 \\
 3 &10 & -5 & a^2+4a+1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 4 & -3 & 2 \\
 0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 &a+5&  0 & 0 \\
 3 &10 & -5 & a^2+4a+1
\end{pmatrix}$$

If $a+5=0$, i.e. if $a=5$, then you have a matrix which does not have full rank. So in this case you have that there is more than one solution.

If $a+5\ne 0$, you can divide the third row by $(a+5)$

$$\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 4 & -3 & 2 \\
 0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 &a+5&  0 & 0 \\
 3 &10 & -5 & a^2+4a+1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 4 & -3 & 2 \\
 0 & 1 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 &  0 & 0 \\
 3 &10 & -5 & a^2+4a+1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & -3 & 2 \\
 0 & 0 & -2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 &  0 & 0 \\
 3 & 0 & -5 & a^2+4a+1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & -3 & 2 \\
 0 & 1 &  0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 &  1 & 0 \\
 3 & 0 & -5 & a^2+4a+1
\end{pmatrix}\sim
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 3 & 0 & 0 & a^2+4a+1
\end{pmatrix}$$

The last matrix is rather simple, so I'll leave the rest for you.

You can also check on [WolframAlpha](http://tinyurl.com/ojdpyc6) for which values of $a$ determinant of this matrix is zero. (A square $n\times n$ matrix has full rank if an only if $\det A\ne 0$. So the values for which the determinant is zero are precisely the values you are looking for. This would not work for non-square matrices -- in this case you had the same number of equations as the number of unknowns.)